# Evaluating Iterated Integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

Hi I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out with this problem! I don't understand how to go about the problem, I considered switching to polar coordinates but realized that would be more complicated.

I rationalized the correct answer (part b) by thinking along the lines of area size given by each of the bounds (1-x giving the smallest area). Although, I don't think I'm thinking along the correct lines that this question is looking for!

Comment: Since the integrand is strictly positive and each region of integration contains the previous, that line of reasoning is correct

Comment: All the $dx\,dy$ should be $dy\,dx$. This is an odd error for what appears to be from a textbook exercise.